# NPM unable to find package.json file in React App

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, npm

I've just gone to rerun my React app that I've been working on over the last few weeks and get this

```
C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\matth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-09T22_47_25_246Z-debug.log
```

Log for the error showing

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\matth\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App\package.json'
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\matth\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v12.16.3
9 verbose npm  v6.14.5
10 error code ENOENT
11 error syscall open
12 error path C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App\package.json
13 error errno -4058
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\matth\Documents\GitHub\LoveFoods-App\package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

package.json as below

```
{
  "name": "lovefoods-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.0.0",
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.15.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The thing is, that the package.json file is sitting in the folder and hasn't been moved at all since I last added to the application.
Anyone have any solutions that can help out at all? I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Some process may be holding lock on the file. Visual Studio Code does it sometimes.Try restarting your IDE or even your machine and see if it is resolved.

Comment: @kvp2982 sadly no luck doing that! Would have been a nice straight forward fix though if it had worked

Comment: Can you show an image of `LoveFoods-App` folder

Comment: It can be resolved by npm init command, enter need full details, and npm start command.